# Excel formula with identifying %change on repeated sites and multiple years

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm looking for an Excel formula to drag down on a large dataset. My issue is I have a couple hundred repeated sites with various numbers of years (see subset Excel table example). In the first years' occurrence, the formula is equal to the to the corresponding %change cell but, the following year will note the difference between the current year and previous year (e.g. formula is =D3/D2-1) and the numbers from all years averaged using the average function. I'd like to automate these formulas and have Excel recognize a site name change. I've been attempting IF statements but can't seem to get it right. Any help is appreciated. TIA

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5b0m.png)

Answer (score 0):

So long as your data is sorted so that:  a) All the sites are grouped (as in the pic), and b) All the years are in order from lowest to highest (as in the pic), this is very, very easy.

For the same site/same site work, the sites are grouped so if they are the same site, that column's cells are the same (so, A4=A5, for example, as "Site 1" = "Site 1") and if different, they are NOT the same (so A4<>A5 as "Site 2" <> "Site 3"). A simple `IF()` test then tells whether they match or not and therefore can branch to either of two formulas depending upon the result. So, as in the pic, let's say 2020's Site 1 is cell A11 (so 2019's is A10), and the first Site 2 is A2. Then you might have the following in cell E11:

```
=IF(A11<>A10,D11,D11/D10-1)
```

For E11, it would see A11=A10 so it would do the 2nd formula and result in "1" while for E12, it would see A12<>A11 and do the 1st formula resulting in "0.104651163".

Then the averages. There is a nice function for this as well. It is called `SUMIF()` and it lets you test a range of cells for matching a criterion and if so, sum that range, or some other `not necessarily obviously` matching range. So you can specify your whole column A as the test range, then set the criterion to be "is this the first instance of the column A value (like one does above, just a different goal) and if so, then do the `SUMIF()` and one more thing to get the average, while if not, then give a `""` result.

That other thing would be a similar function Excel offers:  `COUNTIF()` which does precisely what it sounds like it does. So you have the sum of the averages and it provides the quantity of years to divide by letting you have your average. Like so:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",SUMIF($A$2:$A$13000,"="&$A2,$E$2:$E$13000)/COUNTIF($A$2:$A$13000,"="&$A2))
```

The use of `$`'s in the formula is to allow you to fill down without the ranges changing on you, nor the column looked at for the changing Sites.